# D3 rendering stacked bars

Tags: javascript, d3.js, bar-chart, stacked-chart

I'm trying to display the number of bars depending on the amount of rows i have in an array. Currently the numbers of bars displayed is determined by how many elements i have within an array. For example, [2,3,4,5], will display 4 stacked bars. But i want data = [[4, 8, 10],
[50, 20, 20]] which gives me 2 stacked bars.

My code:

```
var margin = { top: 30, right: 30, bottom: 40, left: 50}

var data = [[4, 8, 10],
[50, 30, 20]
,[4, 18, 15],
[50, 20, 20]
];  

var remapped = data.map(function(row) {
return row.map(function(col,i){

return { x: i, y: col };
});
});

var w = 200,
h = 200;

var svg = d3.select(".chart").append("svg:svg")
.attr("width", 4000)
.attr("height", 300 )
.append("svg:g")
.attr("transform", "translate(0,"+h+")");

var x = d3.scale.ordinal().rangeRoundBands([0, w], 0.4, 0.03)
var y = d3.scale.linear().range([0, h])
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
.range(["#98abc5", "#8a89a6", "#7b6888", "#6b486b", "#a05d56", "#d0743c", "#ff8c00"]).domain(data[0].map(function(d,i){return i;}));

var chartContainer = svg.append('g').attr('class', 'bar-chart-container');

var stacked = d3.layout.stack()(remapped)

x.domain(stacked[0].map(function(d) { return d.x; }));
y.domain([0, d3.max(stacked[stacked.length - 1], function(d) { return d.y0 + d.y; })]);



var group = chartContainer.selectAll("svg")
.data(stacked)
.enter().append("svg:g")
.attr("class", "group")
.style("fill", function(d, i) { return color(i); })

var rect = group.selectAll("rect")
.data(function(d){return d;})
.enter().append("svg:rect")
.attr("x", function(d, i) {; return x(d.x); })
.attr("y", function(d,i) { return -y(d.y0) - y(d.y); })
.attr("height", function(d) { return y(d.y); })
.attr("width", x.rangeBand());
```

Many thanks in advance for the time to read this.

Answer (score 1):

Right now, if you have this array:

```
var data = [
    [4, 8, 10], 
    [50, 20, 20]
];
```

Your `remapped` will be an array with 2 arrays (each one having 3 objects), like this:

```
var remmaped = [
    [{ x: 0, y: 4},
     { x: 1, y: 8},
     { x: 2, y: 10},
    ],
    [{ x: 0, y: 50},
     { x: 1, y: 20},
     { x: 2, y: 20},
    ]
];
```

And that gives you the expected result: 3 groups of stacked bars, each one having 2 bars.

But, if I understood it right, you want [4, 8, 10] to be the values of the first group and [50, 20, 20] to be the values of the second group, i.e, having only 2 stacked bars (each one with 3 bars). You can do 2 different things to achieve this:

- Changing the way the `remapped` variable is created;
- transposing the original matrix.

I did the second one, transposing the matrix using this function:

```
var newData = data[0].map(function(col, i) { 
    return data.map(function(row) { 
        return row[i] 
    })
});
```

Then we use `newData` to create `remapped`, which is now an array having 3 arrays with 2 objects each.

In this fiddle, using as data `[[4, 8, 10], [50, 20, 20]]` you have 2 groups of stacked bars: https://jsfiddle.net/gerardofurtado/f8j4jm5n/

Comment: Thank you for the reply and answer. Sorry i didn't mention this earlier, originally the remapped variable was being created like the newData variable. The reason for the change was because I wanted each stacked bar to be grouped individually. Is it possible to achieve the same result but the stacked bars are grouped individually?

Comment: What do you mean by "stacked bars grouped individually"?

Comment: The stacked bars have no reference to another stacked bar when doing an inspect element. So when i do an inspect element, only that stacked bar is highlighted. If that makes sense?

Comment: That's the normal behaviour.

Comment: is there a way to change that?

Comment: Sorry, I really don't understand what you want. Let's see if someone else gives you an answer. Cheers.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, would it help if I say I’m looking for a way to group the rects by column?

Comment: Do you mean something like this? https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3887051 . In that case, you should not use stack layout.

Comment: I mean something like this, https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3886208. What I need is a way to have each bar within a stack not referring to other stack bars of the same color. Similar to how it's done in the example. If you carry out an inspect element that might make more sense. I'm sorry for the confusion.